# What measures can be taken to prevent accidental data deletion in Hive?

Tags: hive

Today I accidentally declared a table as an non-external table and then dropped it, causing the underlying data to be deleted. What are things that I can do to prevent doing something like this (apart from backing up, which we do)?

We pretty much exclusively use external tables, so it would be great if we could turn the non-external table feature completely off, or require a flag like FORCE when we declare one etc.

Note: We use Hive version 0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a nice solution for your use case.

A quick and dirty solution would be to change the permissions of your warehouse directory so that the it cannot be written to. This would prevent the creation of internal tables except by the HDFS super user. You could give a user/group permissions so that if you needed to create an internal table you could by switching users. There might be unintended consequences from this solution, but I cannot think of any off hand as long as you completely stay away from managed tables.

A more difficult and higher maintenance solution would be to patch the Hive source to disallow creating tables without the EXTERNAL keyword/make EXTERNAL the default/require a FORCE keyword to make a managed table/whatever the exact behavior your want is.

The last solution I can think of is to be really careful to make all tables EXTERNAL. Obviously not a perfect solution or you would not have asked the question, but it would be the one I used. You are the most well positioned to decide if the risks and costs of the other solutions are worth the benefit.